# External monitor shows colors not right

Tags: display, preferences, color, macos

I got a new extra-wide display. Unfortunately, my MacBook is not right configured to the monitor. The colors on it seem too bright, lacking contrast and color. I made sure that the issue is my MacBook since other computers display colors well on the new monitor. Also, my MacBook displays colors well on my old monitor. When I first got the new monitor the colors were displayed correctly but, after attempting to attach two HDMI's to create a dual-screen, the colors got disturbed.

Is there a way to delete the configurations saved of the new monitor from my MacBook? I think if he sees the monitor as a "new" device the colors will go back to normal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to change the color profile in **System Preferences** > **Displays** > **Display Settings** > **Color Profile**? You may even need to create a new profile and/or calibrate the new or existing profile.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It is either too difficult for me to calibrate myself or not fixing the issue. The adjustments I made, make no impact on the weird glance my MacBook projects.

Comment: Have you tried changing the brightness & contrast through the monitor’s inbuilt menu?

Comment: Yes, already tried that.